# GRPC metadata not updating in Go

Tags: go, grpc-go

I'm trying to write a unary interceptor to add a request ID to incoming requests:

```
func RequestIDInterceptor(ctx context.Context, req interface{},
    info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (val interface{}, err error) {

    newCtx := ctx
    newCtx = createAndSetMetadata(newCtx, metadata.FromIncomingContext, metadata.NewIncomingContext)
    newCtx = createAndSetMetadata(newCtx, metadata.FromOutgoingContext, metadata.NewOutgoingContext)

    md, ok := metadata.FromOutgoingContext(newCtx)
    fmt.Printf("After update. Metadata: %v, Found: %t\n", md, ok)

    return handler(newCtx, req)
}

func createAndSetMetadata(ctx context.Context, getter func(context.Context) (metadata.MD, bool),
    setter func(context.Context, metadata.MD) context.Context) context.Context {

    meta, ok := getter(ctx)
    fmt.Printf("Found? %t, Metadata: %v\n", ok, meta)
    if !ok {
        meta = metadata.New(map[string]string{})
        ctx = setter(ctx, meta)
    }

    meta.Set("X-Request-Id", "TEST_REQUEST_ID")
    fmt.Printf("Metadata: %v\n", meta)
    return ctx
}
```

This code works as expected when the request doesn't include metadata (`RequestIDInterceptor(context.Background(), nil, nil, handler)`) but if the context includes metadata then the ID won't populated. Essentially, the output looks like this:

```
WITHOUT METADATA
Found? false, Metadata: map[]
Metadata: map[x-request-id:[TEST_REQUEST_ID]]
Found? false, Metadata: map[]
Metadata: map[x-request-id:[TEST_REQUEST_ID]]
After update. Metadata: map[x-request-id:[TEST_REQUEST_ID]], Found: true

WITH METADATA
Found? true, Metadata: map[]
Metadata: map[x-request-id:[TEST_REQUEST_ID]]
Found? true, Metadata: map[]
Metadata: map[x-request-id:[TEST_REQUEST_ID]]
After update. Metadata: map[], Found: true
```

To my understanding, the reason this is probably happening is that `metadata.MD` is being passed by value rather than by reference, so updates are being discarded when `createAndSetMetadata` returns. How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `metadata.FromOutgoingContext` effectively returns a deep copy of the `metadata.MD` found in the context. You can check [the sources](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/v1.50.1/metadata/metadata.go#L262), it's still true as of `google.golang.org/grpc@v1.50`.

So directly writing to it (the copy) as you would do with a map simply doesn't affect the `MD` that is stored in the context.

You have to call the setter again to propagate the new values:

```
func createAndSetMetadata(/* args */) context.Context {
    // ...
    return setter(ctx, meta)
}
```

Comment: That makes sense; I assumed it was a shallow/deep copy problem but I couldn't see why it was working when there was no metadata at all. Thanks for your answer!